# Avoid Displaying Success or Failure message twice while inserting Array items in database using php

Tags: mysql, php

I insert values that have been checked in a PHP table, but what happens is when I select more than one item, I receive more than one success or failure message.

**This is my code for inserting in the database.**

```
//insert.php  
include_once 'includes/dbconnect.php';
if(!empty($_POST['perms']))
{
    $output = '';
    $perms = $_POST['perms'];
    $role = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['role']);
    $module = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['module']);
    foreach ($perms as $perm) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO roles_permissions (role_id,module_id,perm_id)
                VALUES ('$role','$module','$perm')"; 
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query))
    {
    $output .= '
        <script>
            bootbox.alert("<h4>Success:</h4> <p>Permissions have been added to selected role successfully </p>",function(){
             window.location.reload(); });
        </script>';
    } else {
        $output .= '
        <script>
            bootbox.alert("<h4>Sorry!</h4><p>Operation was not successful, Please cross check and try again.</p> ",function(){ window.location.reload(); });
        </script>';
    }
    }
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Thanks for your help in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You receive more than one success message because the code that builds the messages is Inside your foreach loop. If you only want one message you must move it outside the loop.

```
<?php
//insert.php  
include_once 'includes/dbconnect.php';

if(!empty($_POST['perms'])) {
    $output = '';
    $perms = $_POST['perms'];
    $role = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['role']);
    $module = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['module']);
    foreach ($perms as $perm) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO roles_permissions (role_id,module_id,perm_id)
                VALUES ('$role','$module','$perm')"; 

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        // if we get an error stop the loop
        if ( ! $result) { break; }
    }

    if ($result) {
        $output = '<script>
                    bootbox.alert("<h4>Success:</h4> <p>Permissions have been added to selected role successfully </p>",function(){
                     window.location.reload(); });
                    </script>';
    } else {
        $output = '<script>
                    bootbox.alert("<h4>Sorry!</h4><p>Operation was not successful, Please cross check and try again.</p> ",function(){ window.location.reload(); });
                    </script>';

    }
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

> Also your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
>   Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
>   You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

There is also a potential speed benefit when using prepared statements, as you can prepare the query ones (prepare basically means compile and optimise) and reuse it many times after changing the parameter values

So you code would look like this

```
<?php
//insert.php  
include_once 'includes/dbconnect.php';

if(!empty($_POST['perms'])) {
    $output = '';

    $query = "INSERT INTO roles_permissions 
                    (role_id,module_id,perm_id) VALUES (?,?,?)"; 
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);

    foreach ($perms as $perm) {

        // for the purpose of this example I assumed all 3 values were integers
        $stmt->bind_params('iii', $_POST['role'], $_POST['module'], $prem);
        $result = $stmt->execute();
        // if we get an error stop the loop
        if ( ! $result) { break; }
    }

    if ($result) {
        $output = '<script>
                    bootbox.alert("<h4>Success:</h4> <p>Permissions have been added to selected role successfully </p>",function(){
                     window.location.reload(); });
                    </script>';
    } else {
        $output = '<script>
                    bootbox.alert("<h4>Sorry!</h4><p>Operation was not successful, Please cross check and try again.</p> ",function(){ window.location.reload(); });
                    </script>';

    }
    echo $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help.

Comment: Thanks again for your addition help. but for prepared statements, let me just learning it.